# How to properly redirect bash script execution output when using install command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have wrote this sample bash script which I want to use mainly for installing tools on the remote environment, therefore I need pretty decent logging.

During my script execution I want to capture each step to the console window and to the file which should include all the details about execution together with errors.

How to properly handle install command, currently I can't capture see output in the file.
What are recommended practices in this case? 
I've seen solutions using additional variables to capture output it but don't know how to use it in my case...

```
$output="$(comand 2>&1)"
```

Thanks

```
#!/bin/bash
logFile="/log.log"
>$logFile
printLog(){
    echo "[$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")]:" "$@" "Exit Code: $?" 2>&1 | tee -a $logFile
}
sampleFunc1(){
    printLog $LINENO "sampleFunc1"
    printLog $LINENO && mkdir "/dir1/dir2" && mkdir -p "/dir3/dir4" && mkdir -p "/dir5/dir6" && touch "file.txt" && cp "/file2.txt" "/dir1/dir2/"
    printLog $LINENO "sampleFunc1"
    printLog $LINENO ""
}
sampleFunc2(){
    printLog $LINENO "sampleFunc2"
    array=("/dir1/dir2" "/dir3/dir4" "/dir5/dir6")
    for i in "${array[@]}"
    do
        if [ -d "$i" ]
        then printLog $LINENO "exists $i"
        else printLog $LINENO "creating $i"
            mkdir -p "$i"
        fi
    done
    printLog $LINENO "sampleFunc2"
    printLog $LINENO""
}
sampleFunc3(){
    printLog $LINENO "sampleFunc3"
    printLog apt-get -qq install someApp
    printLog $LINENO "sampleFunc3"
    printLog $LINENO ""
}
sampleFunc1
sampleFunc2
sampleFunc3
```

Comment: 0. shellcheck.net is your friend. 2. Use exit codes. 3. tee does not append by default.

Comment: You might want to familiarize yourself with how to ask questions on stack overflow. In particular, it's best to create a [minimum example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and to ask one particular question, rather than everything that you are confused with. This makes it more likely that all your questions will be answered, and has the added benefit that SO will show you similar, answered questions so you don't ask something twice. If you had asked question 3 separately, SO may have been able to show you questions like it that could help you solve your problem.

Comment: Point take about separate questions, but if it comes to the minimum example - this is my minimum example as I wanted to show what type of execution I'm trying to capture. I'will make an edit based on the hints you already gave me. Thx

Comment: @jeremysprofile shellcheck.net is a cool tool! points problems fast, but at the same I fixed suggested double quotes but when testing on my system it would complain about that. Thx for pointing these things.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm you use this snippet for perfoming remote tasks? It's right you can capture output in a file, but I would recomment you remote execution frameworks for things like this. Such tools take proper care of output from tools and can submit theire parsed output to logging systems.

By the way if you not run this snippet you will get problems in privilege escalation, at the point where you call "apt"